# Issue in displaying autocomplete dropdown properly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have implemented autocomplete feature in reactjs but when I type in some input the dropdown i.e autocomplete suggestions get displayed behind the cards. Actually it should be displayed in front side but currently the card is overlapping that dropdown. How can I move it to frontside ? (See screenshot for better understanding)

Code:

```
    render() {

        const {
          onChange,
          onClick,
          onKeyDown,
          state: {
            activeSuggestion,
            filteredSuggestions,
            showSuggestions,
            search
          }
        } = this;

        let suggestionsListComponent;

        if (showSuggestions && search) {
          if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
            suggestionsListComponent = (
              <ul className="suggestions">
                {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
                  let className;

                  // Flag the active suggestion with a class
                  if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                    className = "suggestion-active";
                  }

                  return (
                    <li
                      className={className}
                      key={suggestion}
                      onClick={onClick}
                    >
                      {suggestion}
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            );
          } else {
            suggestionsListComponent = (
              <div className="no-suggestions">
                <em>No suggestions, you're on your own!</em>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="header">
            <div className="md-form mt-0 customsearch">
                <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search projects" aria-label="Search"
                value={this.state.search}
                onChange={this.searchTermChanged} 
                />
                {suggestionsListComponent}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              {this.state.projects.map((val,index) => (
                <div class="col-3">
                  <Card title={val.title} by={val.by} blurb={val.blurb} 
                  url={val.url} funded={val.funded} backers={val.backers} imgurl={index}/>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried moving it inside div of container fluid but it doesn't work ?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you just need to apply higher z-index to the autocomplete container than the other container

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet So I should add `z-index: -1;` in header className is it right ? I am displaying dropdown as follows ->  `{suggestionsListComponent}` which is inside header class and cards are displayed in container-fluid class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Toni Michel Caubet in the comment. You need to add `z-index: 1` to parent container. As you want search suggestions in front of card so add z-index: 1 to customsearch class.

Code:

```
.customsearch {
    z-index: 1;
}
```